# Aysmptotic variance of an estimator of the parameter of an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance, exponential-distribution

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

There is a hint: you may use the expression for gamma function. But I don't know how to use it since it the sum of squares of exponential random variables. I computed the expression of the asymptotic variance in an extremely complicated way. The result is $\frac 1{2\theta^2}~$ but I don't know if its correct. Does anyone know how to use the hint? Thank you.

Comment: This result is wrong. The right answer should be $\frac{5}{4\theta^2}$. This is the result of Delta method. But I do not know how to use hint.

Comment: Try to use MathJax instead of posting images.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way is to use the Delta method. However, it is sometimes possible to apply tricks that make calculations easier. And this is just such a case if you are familiar with the Slutsky's theorem.
Denote $\overline {X^2}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}$
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(T_2-\frac1\theta\right)=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{\frac12\overline {X^2}}-\frac1\theta\right)
$$
Multiply and divide by the conjugate: 
$$
=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac12\overline{X^2}-\frac1{\theta^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac12\overline {X^2}}+\frac1\theta} = \sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X^2}-\frac2{\theta^2}\right)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac12\overline {X^2}}+\frac2\theta} 
$$
$$
=\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X^2}-\mathbb E[X_1^2]\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2T_2+\frac2\theta}
$$
Consider multipliers separately: 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X^2}-\mathbb E[X_1^2]\right) \xrightarrow{\mathcal D_\theta} \mathcal N(0, \text{Var}(X_1^2)).
$$
$$
T_2 \xrightarrow{p} \frac1\theta, 
\quad\text{ then } \quad
\frac{1}{2T_2+\frac2\theta}\xrightarrow{p}\frac\theta4.
$$

Next, Slutsky's theorem implies that the product converges in distribution to 
$$
\mathcal N(0, \left(\frac\theta4\right)^2 \cdot \text{Var}(X_1^2)).
$$

You need to calculate $\text{Var}(X_1^2)$, and for it you definitelyneed to use Gamma function.